# Console not handling escape sequences

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, terminal

Trying to build an SSH client but have hit a roadblock.
I'm using C# and the library SSH.NET.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new SshClient("host", "username", "password"))
        {
            client.Connect();
            var stream = client.CreateShellStream("vt220", 80, 12, 400, 100, 1024);

            new Task(() => 
            { 
                while (true)
                {
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        Console.Write((char)stream.ReadByte());
                    }
                }
            }).Start();
            new Task(() => 
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (stream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        stream.Write(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }).Start();
            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is my escape sequences are not being handled properly.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygul7.png)

In the screenshot I'm trying to run the 'clear' command, it doesnt work.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Also depends on what your Windows version is. This only got improved in recent Windows 10 builds, like from 2 years ago and onwards.

Comment: Don't use the Task constructor

Comment: @TanveerBadar I use the latest Windows version.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Would a thread be better?

Comment: Also don't do this `while (true) ;`

Comment: @MichaelRandall The while loop is to keep the program from shutting down, how should I keep the thread busy without it?

Also, I tried using Threads instead of Tasks, doesnt make any difference.

Comment: `Console.ReadKey()`

Comment: @MichaelRandall I would, but I'm already using Console.ReadKey() above in the writing to stream.

Comment: @Tygo You have a busy wait in the other `while (true)` loop though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson But it's in a thread right, it wouldnt matter, apart from performence, which I'm not looking for at the moment, I just need a working example.

Comment: @MichaelRandall It would enormously help the OP if you also posted what to do rather than just what not to do.